# What is the argument of $1-\bar{z}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

Let $z=\rho e^{i\theta}$ be a complex number. What is the argument of $1-\bar{z}$ in terms of $\theta$? Is it $\pi-\theta$ because the argument of $-\bar{z}$ is $\pi-\theta$?

Follow-up: Is there a way to simplify the argument: $\arctan\left(\frac{\rho\sin\theta}{1-\rho\cos\theta}\right)$?

Comment: I'm pretty sure argument will also depend on $\rho$

Comment: It will have to be in terms of $\rho$ too. $1-\overline{z}=(1-\rho\cos(\theta))+i\rho\sin(\theta)$ is the binomial form. You can take the quotient $\frac{\rho\sin(\theta)}{1-\rho\cos(\theta)}$, which is the tangent of the argument.

Comment: @fatherBrown "binomial form?"

Comment: $e^{i\theta}=\cos{\theta}+i\sin{\theta}$ is the binomial form

Comment: @MarkViola What is your question?

Comment: So, $1-\overline{z}=1-\rho e^{-i\theta}=1-(\rho\cos{\theta}-i\rho\sin{\theta})=(1-\rho\cos{\theta})+i\rho\sin{\theta}$

Comment: It is the Cartesian form, not the binomial form.

Comment: Geometrically as well for a general $z$, it would depend on $\rho$

Comment: Is there a way to simplify $\arctan(\frac{\rho\sin\theta}{1-\rho\cos\theta})$?

Comment: The $\rho$ is problematic.  If $\rho=-1$, you can show that argument is $-\theta/2$.

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way.

Comment: @MarkViola Who appointed you arbiter elegantiarum? That you like to call it Cartesian form doesn't mean that everyone calls it that way.

Comment: @fatherbrown I appointed myself.  ;-) And most call it Cartesian or Rectangular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\tan\left(-\frac{\theta}{2}\right)=\frac{\sin{(-\theta)}}{1+\cos{(-\theta)}}=\frac{-\sin\theta}{1+\cos\theta}=\frac{-\sin\theta}{1-(-\cos\theta)}$

if $\rho=-1$, you would have $\frac{\rho\sin{\theta}}{1-\rho\cos\theta}$ which is the form you are looking for.  I don't know if there is any other way to reduce for other values of $\rho$, but in general, i believe it is as far as you can go.